Unable to nest basic vanilla web component
I have a set of basic web components made out of plain JS. Example:
Account.ts
class Account extends HTMLElement{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.innerHTML = '<p>My account</p>';
   }
}

customElements.define('account', Account);

Basket.ts
class Basket extends HTMLElement{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.innerHTML = '<p>My Basket</p>';
   }
}

customElements.define('basket', Basket);

I am trying to create another web component (common) that can be nested in each of the above. For now, lets assume a basic <button> with a click event. I have tried:
CommonButton.ts
class CommonButton extends HTMLElement{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.innerHTML = '<button onclick="console.log('clicked')">Click Me</button>';
   }
}

customElements.define('common-button', CommonButton);

Account.ts
class Account extends HTMLElement{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.innerHTML = `
          <p>My Account</p>
          <common-button></common-button>
      `;
   }
}

customElements.define('account', Account);

There are no errors in the browser. I can see in the generated HTML:
<account>
     <p>My Account</p>
     <common-button></common-button>
</account>

However no <button> inside of <common-button>

When testing this code I get various other errors.  Most relevant are that CommonButton has a syntax error in a mis-quoted string and <account> isn't a valid custom element name.  When I correct these, the code works as expected for me.  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

Have tried recreating here but works as it should: https://stackblitz.com/edit/customelement-fj7u4c?file=index.js,button.js

There probably is no DOM in the constructor then innerHTML fails (run document.createElement("common-button") in the console to see the proper error messages. The connectedCallback tells you when the Web Component was attached to the DOM; use the connectedCallback

Your custom element names are invalid, they must start with a letter, contain at least one -,  and have another valid character after that. It's not allowed to create children in the constructor.


Your custom element names are invalid, they must start with a letter, contain at least one -, and have another valid character after that.

It's not allowed to create children in the constructor. Instead, use shadow DOM and create your elements there (which is allowed!).


That being fixed, here you go:


class Account extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({ mode:'open' })
        .innerHTML = `
          <p>My Account</p>
          <common-button></common-button>
      `;
   }
}

customElements.define('foo-account', Account);


class CommonButton extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({ mode:'open' })
        .innerHTML = `<button onclick="console.log('clicked')">Click Me</button>`;
   }
}

customElements.define('common-button', CommonButton);
<foo-account></foo-account>



